# How much of a thread's code get executed ever time it is scheduled?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, scheduling, fwrite

I have 3 threads in my program

t1
reads a frame1 of data and
writes it onto a hard disk

t2
reads a frame2 of data and
writes it onto a hard disk

t2
reads a frame3 of data and
writes it onto a hard disk

When the program runs, and t1 t2 and t3 are scheduled for execution one by one, how are the operations performed internally?

Ex:
say t1 -> t2 -> t3 get scheduled in this order

Scenario 1:
will t1 finish one full cycle of read frame1 and write frame1 before t2 is scheduled and whether t2 finishes one full cycle of read frame2 and write frame2 before t3 is scheduled and so on?

or

Scenario 2:
can t1 or t2 or t3 or few or all of these threads' execution be stopped in the middle of their execution before the next thread gets scheduled?

Which of these scenarios is correct?

I am especially mentioning hard disk write as there is a possibility of a blocking fwrite call, which cannot be left in the middle of its execution

Answer (score 2):

You should consider (and code and *think*) as if all threads are running concurrently (e.g. a the same time on different cores of your processor).

A thread usually don't write directly to the disk: it is writing files to some [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (and the kernel is buffering, e.g. in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), so the disk IO can happen several seconds later).

If you need [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29), you should make it *explicitly* (e.g. with [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)). If you need to synchronize file contents, consider using some [file locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) machinery à la [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) (but you should really avoid having several threads or processes accessing and writing the same file). BTW *stdio* is buffered (so you might want to [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) after [fwrite(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html)...)

And when the kernel is [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) some thread or process, it will schedule [preemptively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) at arbitrary time (at any [*machine* instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)).

Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Read also about [memory models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_%28programming%29) (it is *tricky*).

So **all your scenarii** could and are likely to **be *wrong***.

> How much of a thread's code get executed ever time it is scheduled?

You should not care, and you cannot know. It can be as tiny as nothing (read about [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)), and as large as several millions machine instructions. BTW, be aware of [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) and of [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in C; so actually the question does not even make sense (from the observable point of view of a C programmer).

> I am especially mentioning hard disk write as there is a possibility of a blocking `fwrite` call

When the *stdio* library (or directly your application) is actually [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)-ing a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), it is likely (but not certain) that the kernel will schedule tasks during such [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). However, the actual disk IO will happen probably later.

PS. Read also about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the method (or methods) these threads are calling. If all these threads are calling a same method and if that method is synchronized then only one thread will be processing it at a time. During that time rest of the threads will wait for currently running thread to complete. If not synchronized or threads are calling different methods then there is no guarantee which thread will get processed first or finish first. They also may end up overwriting class-level variables.

Comment: in this case, say there is no common data between the threads

Comment: But are these threads calling the same method? And is method synchronized?

Comment: they are not calling any common method

Comment: If they are not calling any common synchronized methods, then there is no waiting involved. JVM will fire up threads upon thread availability (as and when they get freed up from thread pool). The very reason you are doing it in multiple threads is you want async/parallel processing. There is no guarantee which thread will start first or finish first. You can however wait for all the threads to complete before you do something else...