# Threads and confusion about the order of execution

Tags: java, multithreading

I just can't understand the order in which the program executes.

```
public class sub  {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        base b1 = new base();
        b1.s="b1";
        b1.start();
        base b2 = new base();
        b2.s="b2 ";
        b2.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}

public class base extends Thread{

    String s;
    @Override
    public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s+" "+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

The output is

```
b2  0
b1 0
b2  1
b1 1
b2  2
b1 2
b1 3
b2  3
b2  4
b1 4
```

Could anyone please explain why the output is in this order. why is that first b2 is executing before b1 and not b1 before b2. Then why is b1 is executing first.

Comment: In an asynchronous execution (when you start multiple thread) there is no guarantee which thread will start first or complete first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306342/how-much-of-a-threads-code-get-executed-ever-time-it-is-scheduled/40306449#40306449

Comment: And if you want to control the order ,try ExecutorService. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153663/controlling-task-execution-order-with-executorservice

Comment: If you want a specific execution order why are you using threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that one thread will be chosen to run before another. In this case what could be happening is that the scheduler tries to avoid context switches so it will try to keep the main thread running. Also it takes time to start a new thread. Maybe by the time the main thread goes to sleep both b1 and b2 are started, which starts running first and which is chosen to acquire the lock on the stdout printstream are both arbitrary choices at that point.